# Symfony : File .env.local not taken into account

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I have a problem with my project, since the beginning it seems that the .env.local is not taken into account. I have my .env like that:

```
APP_ENV=
APP_SECRET=secret

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
MAILER_USER=someaddress@mail.tld
MAILER_URL=sendmail://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> symfony/ldap ###
LDAP_HOST=
LDAP_PASS=
LDAP_BASE_DN=
LDAP_SEARCH_DN=
LDAP_UID_KEY=sAMAccountName
LDAP_FILTER=(&(objectClass=Person)({uid_key}={username}))
###< symfony/ldap ###


 DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/intranet?serverVersion=mariadb-10.3.22&charset=utf8
```

And then I want to override some vars so I did that in my .env.local:

```
APP_SECRET=secret

###> symfony/ldap ###
LDAP_HOST="blabla"
LDAP_PASS="blabla"
LDAP_BASE_DN="blabla"
LDAP_SEARCH_DN="blabla"
###< symfony/ldap ###
```

But when I try to access those vars, I get the one from my .env. I've tested various things, like the .env without the vars I need and define them only in the .env.local but then I get the error:

```
Environment variable not found: "LDAP_HOST".
```

I really have no idea why it is not working. While trying to debug, Thanks a lot

Comment: To start with, your .env.local needs to be a copy of .env.  There is no merging going on.  If .env.local exists then it is used and .env is ignored.  So fix that up and see if it helps.  If not then maybe temporarily try removing .env completely and see what happens.  You should not need to do this but maybe some other portion of your code is trying to access it directly.  Which is a no no.  Also consider creating a new test project and just experimenting a bit and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, creating new .env, removing .env => got an error saying "need a .env", I tried to make a copy of .env and name it .env.local and just modify one data, then accessing it but I kept getting the data from .env. I don't access it in my code. I'm working on a project with collegues, each one of us has a local with our code and all, their .env.local is working perfectly but not mine and we don't see why it's not working.

Comment: Sometimes when you "try a lot of things" you can introduce an error without noticing and it can be hard to track down.  I don't see enough info in your question to help.  Again I would suggest creating a new Symfony project and installing just the LDAP bundle.  Then copy .env to .env.local and see what happens.  I am also assuming that this is all happening the development environment.

Comment: Yes of course I am in the development environment. Even though I start a new project and .env.local works, I don't see how it can help me resolve this one when it's not on the same environment/ project ^^ But I will try

Comment: @Cerad I tried, and it worked fine on the new project.

Comment: So now you have a working starting point.  You can compare to the non-working project and maybe track down the issue.  Or you can copy more of the non-working project to your new project and see if you can recreate the problem.  And of course triple check that you have LDAP_HOST defined in .env.local and that no control codes or whatever slipped in.

Comment: But the thing is, if I copy everything, it's still not working. But if I copy little bits by little bits, it doesn't work either because some files/dependencies are missing.

Comment: Make sure you are not trying to read from `.env.local` while in **test** environment, as the phpdoc to `\Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv::loadEnv` explicitly says: _.env.local is always ignored in test env because tests should produce the same results for everyone._